# Where`s the generated javascript code of my Angular app for event binding?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to understand how Angular generates the javascript.

My html is:

```
<button (click)="show = !show;>Show up</button>
<p *ngIf="show">secret paragraph</p>
```

My ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app3-directives',
  templateUrl: './directives.component.html'
})
export class DirectivesComponent {      
  show = false;
  clicks = [];

  constructor() { }

}
```

**Any other code mentioned from here on, is from the Angular 8, not mine.**

The generated code when I inspect on the browser is:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>My Angular Demo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style>/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */

/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjozLCJzb3VyY2VzIjpbInNyYy9zdHlsZXMuY3NzIl0sIm5hbWVzIjpbXSwibWFwcGluZ3MiOiJBQUFBLDhFQUE4RSIsImZpbGUiOiJzcmMvc3R5bGVzLmNzcyIsInNvdXJjZXNDb250ZW50IjpbIi8qIFlvdSBjYW4gYWRkIGdsb2JhbCBzdHlsZXMgdG8gdGhpcyBmaWxlLCBhbmQgYWxzbyBpbXBvcnQgb3RoZXIgc3R5bGUgZmlsZXMgKi9cbiJdfQ== */</style><style>.fg-white[_ngcontent-evw-c0] {color: white}</style></head>
<body>
  <app3-directives _nghost-evw-c0="" ng-version="8.2.13">
    <button _ngcontent-evw-c0="">Display Detais</button>
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}-->
    <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}--></app3-directives>

<script src="runtime.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.js" type="module"></script><script src="styles.js" type="module"></script><script src="vendor.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
    
</body></html>
```

I did search on the referenced js files, but I found no reference for my button (_ngcontent-evw-c0).

I also inspected the event listeners:

[image]

That points to zone-evergreen.js's function `const globalZoneAwareCallback = function (event) {`, (which I found out is the same code as this http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js included (by Angular?))

So now I know the target function, but where`s the code binding my button to that function?

Comment: What would you gain from this? Angular job is basically encapsulating said logic so you never have to worry about that.

Comment: https://blog.bitsrc.io/event-binding-mechanism-in-angular-b38f0e46d2ed

Comment: I recommend you to see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0o-4yc2n-8 to understand how Angular works behind the scene. The reference for your button is generated by Angular itself, it helps to encapsulate your css logic inside for your component

Comment: @MinusFour excellent question, I would love to find out this answer as well.

Comment: I found now in main.js (I missed it yesterday) that the html will be assigned as a string to `__webpack_exports__["default"]` in main.js. From there on, there's really a lot happening, maybe I'll study it for the sake of curiosity. Thanks for the links!